# Initializing an object without new operator in java

Tags: java

Whats the difference between these two constructors.

```
Circle (Point2D center, double radius) {
    this.center = center;
    this.radius = radius;
}

Circle (Point2D center, double radius) {
    this.center = new Point2D(center.getX(), center.getY());
    this.radius = radius;
}
```

Heres the Point2D class. Both versions of the constructors are working just fine. I am just confused whats the difference.

```
class Point2D {
double x;
double y;

Point2D () {
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
}

Point2D (double x, double y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

void setX (double x) {
    this.x = x;
}

void setY (double y) {
    this.y = y;
}

void setXY (double x, double y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

double getX () {
    return x;
}

double getY () {
    return y;
}

double distance (Point2D p) {
    double x1 = p.getX();
    double y1 = p.getY();
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1 - x, 2) + Math.pow(y1 - y, 2));
}

double distance (double x, double y) {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x - this.x, 2) + Math.pow(y - this.y, 2));
}
```

}

Also the Circle class has 2 fields center and radius. center is type Point2D and radius is type double. I tried compiling and running both versions of the constructor. Both works well. So i am confused which one will be better to use and why, also the difference because in first one i havent used the new operation to initialize the center object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

second constructor uses [defensive copy](http://jtechies.blogspot.ru/2012/07/item-39-make-defensive-copies-when.html) (witch is produced by `Point2D` constructor call) of the original `center` instance  to prevent further mutation (changes) of the input instance that may be very confusing and produce bugs

> So i am confused which one will be better to use and why

the second approach is more safe because your `Point2D` class is mutable. It uses more memory (to hold additional defensive copy) but in real complex projects there are more pros for this design practice than cons.

If you can make `Point2D` class [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) then it will be ok to use the first constructor.

Answer (score 3):

The second constructor creates a new Point instance - `this.center = new Point2D(center.getX(), center.getY());` instead of keeping a reference to the instance passed to it. This means that if the passed `center` is later modified, the changes doesn't affect the `Circle` instance.

The second constructor is usually safer, since it has a truly private `Point` instance as the center of the `Circle`, while the first constructor shares the `center` with the caller of the constructor.

You can see the difference with this code :

```
Point2D point = new Point2D(10.0, 20.0);
Circle circle = new Circle (point, 4.0);
point.setX (5.0);
System.out.println(circle); // assuming you override toString to display the properties
                            // of the Circle
```

If you use the first constructor, after this code is executed, your circle will have a center of (5.0,20.0), while if you use the second constructor, the circle will have a center of (10.0,20.0);

Comment: So, its like first constructor is not using any space in memory, only the space to store the address of the center object that i passed.

Comment: after use of the first constructor `this.center` and `center` variables hold the same reference of one mutual `Point2D` instance. And after second constructor call one more instance (defensive copy) is created - `this.center` and `center` use independent references (`Point2D` values)

Comment: @Xtr33mm The constructor doesn't use space. The instance variables of your Circle class use space. They use space to store both the reference to a Point2D instance and a double. The second constructor creates an additional Point2D object, so you can say that running a program that uses the second constructor would require more space.

Answer (score 0):

`Point2D` is not immutable, i.e. has properties which can be changed after the point was constructed.

The first constructor of `Circle` just uses the `Point2D` object - now the caller could change the point object which would also affect the circle.

The second constructor of `Circle` makes a *copy* of the `Point2D` object. If the circle keeps the point object private it cannot be changed from outside.

Answer (score 0):

`this.center = center`, you using parameter of `center` object.

`this.center = new Point2D(center.getX(), center.getY())`, you create **new** object of `Point2D` with parameter `center` value.